# delete is not working, instead it is inserting a new empty record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried a lot to delete a record from my DB, but I have failed. Instead of deleting the selected value it is inserting a new empty record into my db. Please help me out.

My Controller is:

```
class CatvaluesController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def destroy
        @catvalue = Catvalue.find(params[:id])
        @catvalue.destroy
        redirect_to catvalues_path
    end
    ....
end
```

and my form is:

```
<%= form_for(@catvalue) do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select :id, @catvalues, :id, :v_name, {}, class: 'drop-down'%>
<%= f.submit 'Destroy', :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to destroy your account?' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's possibly, because you don't add anywhere the type of your server-request. I think you are sending a 'POST' request.
Please add your log-file.

Comment: Did you add any call backs into your model ?

Comment: @Bharatsoni  No I didn't added any callbacks

Comment: @user3383458 here is my log file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9grsrrzxmh84an1/development.log)

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` by default takes `post` method

```
<%= form_for @catvalue, :method => :delete do |f| %>
```

Okay, so I'm now adding url to the form helper, try this one!

```
<%= form_for @catvalue, :url => "/catvalues/#{@catvalue.id}",:method => :delete do |f| %>
```

Comment: am getting this error {{No route matches [DELETE] "/catvalues"}} @RSB

Comment: and you missed a colon symbol at delete, isn't it? @RSB

Comment: post the result of `rake routes` for this controller

Comment: here it is:
catvalues  GET    /catvalues(.:format)           catvalues#index
    POST   /catvalues(.:format)           catvalues#create
new_catvalue  GET    /catvalues/new(.:format)       catvalues#new
edit_catvalue  GET    /catvalues/:id/edit(.:format)  catvalues#edit
catvalue  GET    /catvalues/:id(.:format)       catvalues#show
  PUT    /catvalues/:id(.:format)       catvalues#update
                DELETE /catvalues/:id(.:format)       catvalues#destroy

Comment: @santu47, `@catvalue` must be nil then

Comment: your URL paths are not showing up clearly, update it in your question so that I could see it properly

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `I have declared @catvalue as @catvalue = Catvalue.new in controller#index`

Comment: I have edited the answer try that one, and as @SergioTulentsev said make sure `@catvalue` is not nil.

Comment: I have got what you are trying to implement, let me show you how to do it

Comment: So in the index action you have to select one catvalue and when you click on submit that catvalue will be deleted/ correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a POST request, it will call the create action on your controller hence your empty model.

You have to use the delete http method to call the destroy action on your controller :

```
<%= form_for(@catvalue, :method => :delete) do |f| %>
```

Comment: @Interpidd I got this error after adding the above line:
{syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
...form_for(@catvalue), :method => :delete do |f| @output_buffe...}